# I am having hard time taking pointer structure as a function's parameter in C. I am a beginner and I am confused

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct create
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    float total;
};

struct create Create[3];

float givename(struct create* storage[3]);

int main()
{
    for(int j = 0; j<4; ++j)
    {
        printf("Input a[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].a);
        printf("Input b[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].b);
        printf("Input c[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].c);
        float sum = givename(&Create);
        printf("%f", sum);
     }
}

float givename(struct create* storage[3])
{
    for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i)
    {
         storage[i]->total = storage[i]->a + storage[i]->b + storage[i]->c;
         return storage[i]->total;
     }
}
```

This is something I wrote and of course it doesn't work, it might seem stupid to elitist C programmers but a help would be appreciated. I wanted to take an input into array of structure and then use it inside a function that has been called by reference.
**Please tell me can someone help me show what I am misunderstanding with the logic ?**

Comment: You access 4 elements of an array of size 3.

Comment: @PaulHankin it wouldn't work still.

Comment: There's many problems with this code. It's there a specific one you want to fix, for example one causing a compiler error?

Comment: Taking input to the function, and function should be called by reference.

Comment: `struct create* storage[3]` is an array of pointers but `&Create` is a pointer to an array of structs

Comment: And if you're free to point out the mistakes and how to solve each that would be great! @PaulHankin

Comment: @Gerhardh, oh yeah that makes sense. How do I take arrays into that function ?

Comment: StackOverflow is no "fix-all" service. You are supposed to ask specific questions to specific problems (one question per post).  Do you try to run that code and it doesn't work? (What happens, what should happen, what input do you provide) Or do you want to fix compiler warnings? (What message do you get? Where do you get it?)

Comment: Try `givename(Create);` and `float givename(struct create storage[])`

Comment: The thing is, even if you fix the compiler error for me. I wouldn't get it, I want to understand what I am doing wrong and what should be done to solve this issue, so that I could learn and never stuck into problem like this @Gerhardh

Comment: If you ask for compiler messages you will get an explanation for them. Or a link to one of the duplicates. But you just throw the whole code at us and tell us "it doesn't work". You will learn much less with that approach

Comment: @Gerhardh, But I want to pass structure pointer as a parameter.

Comment: Array arguments decay to pointers to the first element. You are actually passing pointers. Not an array of pointers but only one pointer you can use to access all elements. It is exactly the same as `float givename(struct create *storage)`. Note:As the array elements are no pointer, you must replace `->` with `.`

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks buddy that's what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function

```c
float givename(struct create* storage[3])
```

takes an array of pointers to `struct create`, you are sending the address of an array of `struct create`. If you want an array of pointers to `struct create`, do it like this:

```c
struct create * array[3];
array[0] = & Create[0];
array[1] = & Create[1];
array[2] = & Create[2];
```

Plus, this function stops during the first iteration, because of the return.

Array's size is 3, you're looping 4 times.

Your `main` needs a return value;

If you wanted to pass the whole array to `givename` (an array of `struct create`, not pointers), you don't need to since `Create` is global;

For each iteration in the first loop (3 after fixing), you iterate the whole array, I doubt this is what you wanted to do.

The following version prompts to fill 3 `struct create`, computes the total for each (and stores it), and prints it.
Is this what you wanted to do ?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct create
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    float total;
};

struct create Create[3];

float givename(struct create * storage);

int main()
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        printf("Input a[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", & Create[j].a);
        printf("Input b[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", & Create[j].b);
        printf("Input c[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", & Create[j].c);
        float sum = givename(& Create[j]);
        printf("%f\n", sum);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

float givename(struct create * storage)
{
    storage->total = storage->a + storage->b + storage->c;
    return storage->total;
}
```

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | yourProgram

>> Input a[1]:Input b[1]:Input c[1]:6.000000
>> Input a[2]:Input b[2]:Input c[2]:15.000000
>> Input a[3]:Input b[3]:Input c[3]:24.000000
```

What you wanted to achieve is quite unclear, and the naming doesn't help, I recommend you to give better names:

- `struct create` doesn't describe what is stored inside

Consider compiling with -Wall -Wextra -Werror.

Comment: "Your main needs a return value;" It is perfectly fine for `main`, not to return a value. It will be automatic `return 0;` in that case.

Comment: It depends of the version (C89 vs C99+), but it's always better to be explicit, so you don't have to remember the special rules of `main`, especially when you're new to C

Answer (score 0):

Your givename() (seems like a bad name) currently only processes one struct as it **returns** inside the loop. And the way you are calling it after each input of 3 integers it would only process a struct (the first struct each time), and not the array of structs. To process the array of structs you could call it after you got all the input - outside the loop taking input. This shows a version processing during the loop for each struct and then a version processing after the loop with all input.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct create
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    float total;
};

struct create Create[3];

float givename(struct create *storage);
float calculate_totals(struct create storage[3]);
float get_grand_total(struct create [3]);

int main()
{
    for(int j = 0; j<3; ++j)
    {
        printf("Input a[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].a);
        printf("Input b[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].b);
        printf("Input c[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].c);
        float sum = givename(&Create[j]);
        printf("%f\n", sum);
    }
    get_grand_total(Create);
    
    /* calculate all totals after input */ 
    for(int j = 0; j<3; ++j)
    {
        printf("Input a[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].a);
        printf("Input b[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].b);
        printf("Input c[%d]:", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Create[j].c);
    }     
    float grand_total = calculate_totals(Create);
    printf("grand total = %f\n",grand_total);    
}

float givename(struct create *storage)
{
    storage->total = storage->a + storage->b + storage->c;
    return storage->total;
}

float get_grand_total(struct create storage[3])
{
    float grand_total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        grand_total += storage[i].total;   
    }
    printf("grand total sum=%f\n",grand_total);
    return grand_total;
}

float calculate_totals(struct create storage[3])
{
    float grand_total = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<3; ++j)
    {
        storage[j].total = storage[j].a + storage[j].b + storage[j].c;
        printf("total for struct %d=%f\n",j+1,storage[j].total);
        grand_total += storage[j].total;
    }
    return grand_total;
}
```

Comment: `total_sum` lacks a return value